# Crash after long GroebnerBasis calculation

Tags: polynomials, crash, groebner-bases

I am running a long computation of a GröbnerBasis and after some hours the kernel crashes.

The memory usage increases enormous, and it crashes, when it reaches somewhat 4 GB RES, however it is running 64 bit Mathematica.

The code is like

```
GroebnerBasis[{L1 L4 s14 - L1 s15 - L4 s24 + s25, 
               L1 L5 s15 - L1 s16 - L5 s25 + s26,
               L2 L4 s24 - L2 s25 - L4 s34 + s35, 
               L2 L6 s26 - L2 s27 - L6 s36 + s37, 
               L3 L5 s35 - L3 s36 - L5 s45 + s46,
               L3 L6 s36 - L3 s37 - L6 s46 + s47, 
               L4 L6 s46 - L4 s47 - L6 s56 + s57, 
               L5 L6 s56 - L5 s57 - L6 s66 + s67}, 
              {L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9, L10}]
```

what could be the issue?

No ulimits are set

Comment: My experience, on a Linux Ubuntu OS, is I get a kernel crash when MaxMemoryUsed  getw toward 7Gb or so. I believe I also have no ulimit set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in `dmesg`

It actually was killed by the out-of-memory killer

Although the computer had more than  4 GB, perhaps the other programs (e.g. Firefox) filled it up

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too. You can restart kernel periodically by code. Search for this post "Self-restarting MathKernel - is it possible in Mathematica?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864643/self-restarting-mathkernel-is-it-possible-in-mathematica?newreg=5d4d976837bb474db3c8aad81ebc6982